# Calculate mean value from list features in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth, landsat, google-earth-api

I created a FeatureCollection containing 63 features with a different date, from one filter per ID.

In each of these 63 features, I created a new property named "matches" that contains a new list of features, which stores a value (called LANDSAT) for each of the 50 samples I disperse in my region.

[image]

Now, I would like to redeem the LANDSAT value of each list item and take the average, how would I do this?

```
 var collection = Collection .select(["NDVI_to_ajust"], ["LANDSAT"])

      var triplets = collection.map(
        function(image) {
        return image.reduceRegions({
          collection: samplesVegPrimaCinquenta, 
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().setOutputs(image.bandNames()), 
          scale: 30,
        }).map(
          function(feature) {

          return feature.set({
            'imageID': image.id(),
            'date': ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('Y-MM-dd')
          })
        });
      }).flatten();
      print(triplets,'triplets') 

    var coord = function(table,rowId, colId, rowProperty, colProperty){
      var rows = table.distinct(rowProperty);
      var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('matches').apply({
        primary: rows,
        secondary: table,
        condition: ee.Filter.equals({
          leftField: rowProperty, 
          rightField: rowProperty
        })
      });
    print(joined,'join by same ID/DATE')
```

Here's the [link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/965b6c65f98fae8523683b057744796b)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to add the mean to each object of the collection you can do:

```
var colWithMeans=joined.map(function(ft){
   ft.set('requestedMean',ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(ft.get('matches'))).aggregate_mean('LANDSAT'));
});
```

And if you want the global mean (mean of means) :

```
var globalMean= colWithMeans.aggregate_mean('requestedMean')
```

Comment: Unfortionately, I got the error "FeatureCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=1_LT05_217074_19850704_00000000000000000000):
AggregateFeatureCollection.mean, argument 'collection': Invalid type. Expected: FeatureCollection. Actual: List<Feature>."  [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5022bf96b5e4a183cbe8664fcf31ed65)

Comment: `ft.set('requestedMean',
   ee.FeatureCollection(
     ee.List(ft.get('matches'))).aggregate_mean('LANDSAT')`

Comment: Thanks for help me,Kuik. I'm tryint to run this script to another different collection, but I have time out error. To continue and finalize this, can you help me? [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/312ba26daa603ac4192ac2c3e55d7cd0)

Comment: If you want more computation time you need to do an export, I think you don't have the choice

Comment: Thanks, Mathieu and Kuik. I've noticed that when I change the input samples of FeatureCollection, a new type of error occurs that: "FeatureCollection (Error) Parameter 'properties' is required."  I dont know that it is because it is similar to the previous that I used [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f589913322160d4e147a08c652958f7a)